# Align Social Icons Together

Tags: css

I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-font-awesome-share-icons/ this plugin to display social icons in my front page blog list below excerpt it is hidden but visible on hover

http://test.ohcampus.com/

See here

I Want it to Look Like This

See any Post Page on the site

Look AT The Social Icons There

..

I use a Manual Solution For The Second Set of Social Icons

I Was Unable to Use The Same For The Front Page.

Comment: Are you just trying to get your Icons to appear next to one another? Could you show us a picture of what the problem is.

Comment: I believe your problem is that the G+ logo does not have any text under it. You could attempt to put in a black ascii character (&nbsp;) to take space but thats not the optimal solution

Comment: i Want them to Stick to Each Other Like A Bar

Comment: and Have a Height of 30px and Width of 80px for individual icons

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the margin on the social icons, they do not fit in one line otherwise. Replace `12px` by `12px 7px`. This fixes the layout issue on your article pages.

```
.social-icons a {
  margin: 12px 7px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Result:

[image]

For the other problem, someone else already suggested what you need to do. Insert a non-breaking space:

```
<span class="apsc-count">&nbsp;</span>
```

Result:

[image]